# Xubuntu on MSI GS66 Stealth: no ethernet found

Tags: drivers, 20.04, xubuntu, lan, msi

I have bought a MSI GS66 Stealth with Killer Gb LAN. I tried everything but I'm not able to see it on xubuntu 20.04. Ideas?
Thanks

```
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b44 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #2
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e91 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black 2018/PC SN720 NVMe SSD
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 3101 (rev 02)
```

and:

```
# lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 58:96:1d:db:cd:06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-64-generic firmware=50.3e391d3e.0 ip=192.168.43.208 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:ad51c000-ad51ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ad200000-ad2fffff memory:ad300000-ad303fff
```

Answer (score 1):

Just upgraded kernel to 5.8 from 5.4 and now it works.